# Hacer que no aparezca el output de un comando en python cuando usas os.system()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

estoy intentando hacer un programa que manda ping a cierto numero de IPs  que ingresa el usuario por medio de la terminal.
por ejemplo:

```
python programa.py 10 20
```

creo que es adecuado mencionar que la computadora en la que va a estar esta herramienta tiene el sistema operativo windows.

```
from sys import argv
from os import system
for ip in range(argv[1], argv[2] + 1):
    ping = system("ping 192.168.0.{}".format(ip))
    if ping == 1
        print("192.168.0.{} está apagada.".format(ip))
    else:
        print("192.168.0.{} está encendida.".format(ip))
```

el problema es que no quiero que aparezca el output del programa, ya que se ve algo así:

```
Haciendo ping a 127.0.0.1 con 32 bytes de datos:
Respuesta desde 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=128
Respuesta desde 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=128
Respuesta desde 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=128
Respuesta desde 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=128

Estadísticas de ping para 127.0.0.1:
    Paquetes: enviados = 4, recibidos = 4, perdidos = 0
    (0% perdidos),
Tiempos aproximados de ida y vuelta en milisegundos:
Mínimo = 0ms, Máximo = 0ms, Media = 0ms
127.0.0.1 está encendida.
```

No quiero que aparezca el output del programa para no distraer al que use la herramienta (en este caso a un familiar que me pidió que le enseñara a ver cuantas personas hay conectadas a su red)
entonces mi pregunta es

¿como puedo evitar que aparezca el STDOUT de un comando en python?

Muchas gracias al que se tome el tiempo a responder mi pregunta :3

Nota:

No necesariamente tiene que ser con os.system(), si es que se puede con otra linea de código no hay problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, `os.system` en la práctica se considera como "deprecated" y no debería usarse en principio excepto para mantener retrocompatibilidad. El sustituto natural es el módulo `subprocess`, mucho más completo y que permite mucho más control y comunicación sobre le proceso lanzado.

Para Python 3.5 en adelante [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) es una buena elección, solo hay que redirigir la salida estándar a  `os.devnull:`

```
import subprocess
from sys import argv

for ip in range(argv[1], argv[2] + 1):
    out = subprocess.run("ping 192.168.0.{}".format(ip), stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)

    if out.returncode == 1:
        print("192.168.0.{} está apagada.".format(ip))
    else:
        print("192.168.0.{} está encendida.".format(ip))
```

Igualmente puedes redirigir `stderr` si lo deseas.

Answer (score 1):

En caso de usar la función "**system(COMANDO)**, podría funcionar lo siguiente:

**Ejemplo**

```
from os import system
os.system("ping TuDirecciónIP > nul")
```

Cuando agrega **"> nul"** al comando, este no va a generar ninguna salida.

Prueba eso y dime cómo te ha ido.